# Show checkbox with image thumbnails

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have lot of thumbnail and I want to show check box on images at left-top side as shown in image. I am displaying thumbnail images in Repeater.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the image and check box in a  container after that absolutely position the checkbox